# Delete row in Excel if a cell does not contain a specific value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet, i need deleted all rows that not contain the phrase "@" on column G until column K.

This is sample data i have

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfqUM.png]

if cell on Column G until Column K not containing "@", Delete Rows

please help me..

Comment: Do you need to do this using VBA? Or is a straight-forward filter-and-delete also an option?

Comment: Yes.. i need to do this using VBA...

Comment: any cell not containing @ or all cells not containing @?

Comment: @nutsch: I think it's *any*. OP seems to want to delete rows without a valid e-mail.

Comment: for all cell if on Column G until K not containing @ then deleted rows

Comment: @Nanashi : yes, i mean delete rows wiithout a valid email

Answer (score 0):

The following macro scans from row 2 and removes rows where columns 2-5 do not contain an `@`:

```
Sub Macro1()
CurRow = 2
While CurRow < Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
  If InStr(1, _
      Sheet1.Cells(CurRow, 2) _
      & Sheet1.Cells(CurRow, 3) _
      & Sheet1.Cells(CurRow, 4) _
      & Sheet1.Cells(CurRow, 5), _
      "@", vbTextCompare) Then
  Else
    Sheet1.Rows(CurRow & ":" & CurRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    CurRow = CurRow - 1
  End If
  CurRow = CurRow + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Using `Instr`, we concatenate the columns of interest (2-5 in my example code above) to create a single string of text. Then we search for `@` within that concatenated string and remove accordingly.

It changes

[image]

into

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can create an additional column containing the following formula:

[image]

`FIND` is used to identify whether an `@` exists within one of the preceding cells, print `No` if not and `Yes` if it does. Now you can filter these elements (`No`), select the range (making sure only the visible cells are selected), delete the rows and remove the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use several loop commands.  Begin by looping through the records that you want to process.  Here is an outline of pseudo-code.

- loop through the columns that you want to process, G through K
- read the value of the cell as a string
- initialize variable `atdetector = "dunno_yet"`
- loop through each character of the string
- if any character = "@"; then `atdetector = "found"`

After looping through each column, if `atdetector = "dunno_yet"`, then "@" was never found.  Delete the row.  Repeat until there are no more rows.